# How to remove the T character from a date in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datetime, mat-table

I am receiving from the API a datetime like this: 2021-03-21T22:00:00

Here is my component.ts

```
 ELEMENT_DATA: ReservationList[];
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['fullName', 'brand', 'model', 'rentalStartDate', 'rentalEndDate', 'pickUpLocation', 'dropOffLocation', 'totalPrice', 'createdOn'];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ReservationList>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

//here the data is taken from the API call
public getAll() {
  let resp = this.service.reservationList();
  resp.subscribe(report => this.dataSource.data= report as ReservationList[])
}
```

In the HTML the date is displayed like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rentalEndDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> RentalEndDate </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rentalEndDate}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

And in the table the date is displayed like this 2021-03-21T22:00:00

I want to have the date displayed without the T character and just the date.

Comment: That's an ISO 8601 date.

Comment: I'd suggest you look into a date parsing library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)

Comment: `element.rentalEndDate.split("T")[0]` gives your first part before T is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to accomplish this:

You could use `String.replace()`:

```js
removeT(input: string) {
  return input.replace('T', ' ');
}
```

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ removeT(element.rentalEndDate) }}</td>
```

You could also use the [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#format-examples) to format the date:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.rentalEndDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss' }}</td>
```

The date pipe is nice because it let's you easily get the date in more readable formats.

Here is what the output would look like with these different methods:

```
Date String                         "2021-03-21T22:00:00"
Date with string.replace('T', ' ')  "2021-03-21 22:00:00"
Date w/Pipe ('yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss')  "2021-03-21 22:00:00"
Date w/Pipe ('yyyy-MM-dd')          "2021-03-21"
Date w/Pipe ('fullDate')            "Sunday, March 21, 2021"
Date w/Pipe                         "Mar 21, 2021"
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! Which of this approaches is the most suitable?

Comment: I'd probably just go with using the pipe, since it already built in to angular.  Smallest possible change to your existing code.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, the changes are small. It worked! Thank you again!